# Express serve static image to React-native app

Tags: node.js, image, reactjs, express, react-native

I'm trying to serve a static image from node js express to my react native app.

I am trying to use the express.static but I am getting the error

> Failed prop type: Invalid prop source supplied to Image.

How do I serve a static image to a react-native app?

**Folder Structure:**

```
--public
-image.png
-app.js
```

**app.js**

```
const app = express();

app.use(express.static('/public'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.status(200).send({
  message: 'API Called',
}));

module.exports = app;
```

**HomePage.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {AppRegistry, Text, View, TextInput, Button, StyleSheet, Image, } from 'react-native';

export default class HomePage extends Component{

  constructor(){
    super();

  render(){
    return(
      <View style={styles.ViewStyle}>
        <Image
          style={styles.Image}
          //{uri: this.getImage(item.teampicture1)}
          source={{uri: 'http://192.168.1.10:8000/image.png'}}
        /> 

      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out I had to use

```
app.use('/image', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

in the app.js.

Then to show the image I had to call the image route with the image name that is in the public folder.

```
source={{uri: 'http://192.168.1.10:8000/image/image.png'}}
```